# SharePoint : "edit properties" greyed out for folders but not files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, folder, read-only

In my SharePoint 2010 site I can't edit properties for folders.

I have full control permission on the whole site.

[image]

Comment: `I don't know how to tell you what SharePoint version it is ` - you can take a full page screenshot and paste it in your question. We will be able to tell the version of SharePoint by the screenshot.

Comment: Hi Denis thank you for your reply, image added